# mongoose find all not sending callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

new mongoose and I am finding the Modal.find() a little troublesome.

I have a expressjs api endpoint /latest/all that should return all products in my mongodb.

```
// Get latest listings
  router.get('/latest/all', function (req, res, next) {
  var json = Product.getAllProductListings();

  res.send(json);
});
```

The below is a product.js modal.

```
   'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');


// Product Schema
var ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    category: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    state: {
        type: String
    },
    target: {
        type: String
    }
});

var Product = module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);

//Add new product request
module.exports.createProductReq = function (newProdReq, callback) {

    newProdReq.save(callback);

};


//Find all products


//Find One
module.exports.getProductByCategory = function (category, callback) {
    var query = {category: category};
    Product.findOne(query, callback);
};

//Find All
module.exports.getAllProductListings = function (docs) {
    var query = {};
    Product.find(query, function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
    });


};
```

The console.log(docs); displays what I expect it too in my console window, however the "docs" is not being passed to the getAllProductListings in the same fashion as the "findOne" before hand.

I have only one return value in the function for getAllProductListings since it doesn't take parameters.

Am definitely doing something silly so please enlighten me if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `getAllProductListings` is asynchronous, you need to send the response in the callback :

```
// Get latest listings
router.get('/latest/all', function (req, res, next) {
Product.getAllProductListings(res);
});
```

And in your `product.js` :

```
//Find All
module.exports.getAllProductListings = function (response) {
var query = {};
Product.find(query, function (err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    response.send(docs);
});
```

Comment: I have a follow up question if you dont mind. This worked well for the task in question when I just need to return the JSON data. 

How do I send this along with a page. For example the cod ebelow shows what am thinking. 

`// Get latest listings page
router.get('/latest', function (req, res, next) {
 Request.getAllRequestListings(res);
 res.render('latest');

});

// Get latest listings from API
router.get('/latest/all', function (req, res, next) {
    Request.getAllRequestListings(res);
});`