# Send obj with page render in expressjs mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, promise

As a follow up to the this post:
[mongoose find all not sending callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824733/mongoose-find-all-not-sending-callback)

I am trying now to send a Object along with a page in my nodejs/expressjs app instead of sending the JSON data as the response only.

The route for my page

```
//Get latest listings page
router.get('/latest', function (req, res) {
    var rL = Request.getAllRequestListingsCb();
    res.render('latest');
});
```

And as per the linked post, it suggest the following below but I need to return a JSON to my route, not send it direct to the client.

```
//Find all. 
module.exports.getAllRequestListings = function (response) {
    var query = {};
    Request.find(query, function (err, docs) {
        response.send(docs);
    });
};
```

Have attempted to use a promise but my rL var keep returning as undefined so the Promise never gets get as "done" and i believe to be because I have not changed it correctly so now am here.

(The end goal is to render a table within the latest page using "handlebars" to display the data from the Json send with the page.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using proper callback chaining as `find` method is asynchronous.

```
//Find all. 
module.exports.getAllRequestListings = function (callback) {
    var query = {};
    Request.find(query, callback);
};
```

Router

```
//Get latest listings page
router.get('/latest', function (req, res) {
    Request.getAllRequestListingsCb(function (err, docs){
        res.render('latest', { rL: docs });
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks very much indeed @abskmj, even worked out how to then limit ad sort the results as well.